# "Sobre Mim" no feminino apenas?

Tags: suporte, perfil

> Se o site tiver algum lugar para definir o sexo, desconsiderem essa postagem. Estou postando porque eu não encontrei.

Fui olhar o meu perfil hoje (faz tempo que não vejo) e me deparei com seguinte mensagem de `placeholder` onde devo descrever algo "sobre mim".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não me importa o texto, pois sempre vi que era uma sátira, com o intuito de fazer a pessoa digitar algo sobre si. Eu mesmo emprego essa ideia.Mas, fiquei curioso e fui ver como está no **SOen**, e tive um surpresa, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu inglês não é muito bom, mas acho que **Cowgirl** também é feminino.

> Mais uma vez, se tiver algum lugar para adicionar o sexo, favor desconsiderar a pergunta.

Eu não ligo muito para isso, pois eu mesmo já esqueci de alterar o gênero de textos em meus sistemas. Porém, o site presa por gêneros, orientação sexual e raças (pelo que pude perceber pelo chat (já teve casos de eu tomar mute por algumas coisas do tipo, :p)). Diante disso, isso foi algo proposital, algo que passou despercebido ou o texto muda de pessoa para pessoa?

Haaaa, já ia me esquecendo. Mesmo que meu inglês não seja bom, sei que **Cowgirl** não significa **Roqueira** (se bem que o Casseta e Planeta eu nem via direito, então não sei se é algo específico (**Organizações Tabajara**)), ou seja, a tradução "buscou longe", kkkkkk.

Comment: Creio não haver mesmo onde configurar se um utilizador é masculino, feminino ou indefinido. Se o sistema sabe, talvez ele sugira um texto no sexo oposto para estimular a mudar e escrever-mos algo pessoal. Se ele não sabe então há 50% chance de estar certo, aí o feminino é tão válido como masculino. Claro que podia estar indefinido mas não vejo mal em estar definido. O @Gabe poderá responder sobre se o sistema sabe ou não essa informação.

Comment: @Sergio Eu pensei no mesmo. O sistema sugerir algo "diferente" é um ponto para alterar. Porém, isso pode ir contra  apolítica pregada pelo site. Por exemplo, ele aceita conexão via Facebook e Google, o que é possível conseguir o sexo. Porém, não ter a opção te alterar no site é algo estranho. Todavia, eu entendi isso como uma sátira e achei interessante, pois realmente chama a atenção. Eu não ligo de continuar assim no site.

Comment: @Sergio Vide alteração do comentário.

Comment: É que o pessoal do SO vou que hoje em dia essa coisa de sexo ta meio complicada, e decidiu nem botar. Só empregam um pessoa hipotética para fins de demonstração. Vai que nem eles sabem a "orientação sexual" da pessoa hipotética. hehe

Comment: Deve ser realmente muito incômodo um lugar cujo default de gênero é diferente do seu.

Comment: @carla Não vejo diferença neste aspecto, e sim a parte onde a pessoa não pode escolher o que prefere. 
Para falar a verdade, só postei essa pergunta de curiosidade, tanto que meu perfil continua a mesma coisa.
Vale lembrar esse é um assunto que já causou alguns "debates" no site. Não vejo problemas em continuar da forma que está, pelo contrário, eu voto à favor de dar um *ar diferente e informal* em sistemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nós não sabemos o gênero de nenhum usuário do site - mesmo quando a conta é associada ao Facebook, Google - e ainda que soubéssemos, dificilmente teríamos uma condicional pra servir duas versões diferentes, considerando o quão fissurados em performance os devs são

A tradução se manteve no feminino porque o material original é assim, e não custa nada dar uma variada... Quanto ao "cowgirl", eu não achei que "vaqueira" era uma tradução que fazia sentido.

Comment: **Você** sabe o gênero de, pelo menos, meia-dúzia (vide encontro SOpt) - quando é o próximo, by the way? ;)

Comment: Por que não faz sentido? Roqueiras programam mas vaqueiras não?

Comment: @carla nada nesse sentido, eu só tive a impressão de que "vaqueira" é uma palavra mais incomum que "roqueira", e portanto me soava mais como uma tradução automática, que era algo que eu queria evitar. Posso ter errado a mão... O que você acha?

Comment: @Gabe Acho que ambos são igualmente válidos, a frase não é pra fazer sentido mesmo. Só fiquei curiosa pra saber pq vc estava procurando sentido numa frase que não tem nenhum.